# Mongodb aggregation match field if it does not exist or has certain value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

There are records in mongodb like following

```
model: Category
{_id: id1, owner: owner1}
{_id: id2, owner: owner1}
{_id: id3, deleted: false, owner: owner1}
{_id: id4, deleted: false, owner: owner2}
{_id: id5, deleted: true, owner: owner1}
{_id: id6, deleted: true, owner:owner1}
```

I want to apply aggregation pipeline where the first step is to match certain owner and match those documents which have either no 'deleted' field or have 'deleted' field with value 'false'.

I could not write the way to express the 'deleted; field in the following query

```
const projects = await Category.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          owner: owner1,
          deleted: < I WANT THIS QUERY >
        },
      }
       ...
    ])
```

The desired result is as follows:

The results should exclude any record which has 'deleted' equal to 'true'
Desired result:

```
results:
{_id: id1, owner: owner1}
{_id: id2, owner: owner1}
{_id: id3, deleted: false, owner: owner1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $or:

```
Category.find({ owner:"owner1",$or:[ {deleted:false} , {deleted:null}]})
```

aggregation example:

```
Category.aggregate([ {$match:{ owner:"owner1",$or:[ {deleted:false} , {deleted:null}]}}     ])
```

Same example , but using $in:

```
 Category.find({ owner:"owner1",deleted:{$in:[ false , null] }} )
```

aggregation example:

```
 Category.aggregate([  {$match:{owner:"owner1",deleted:{$in:[ false , null] }}  }  ])
```

P.S.
Instead of null you can use as well {$exists:false }